# How to stage a redesigned site on a new webhost while the original site is still live?

Tags: wp-config, site-url, staging

thanks in advance for any advice! My client has a live site currently hosted on GoDaddy. I am developing a redesigned site for him on Local. I don't like working on GoDaddy and have advised him to move the new site to a new webhost when it's time to take the new site live. I have set up a staging site on the new webhost so we can both easily make revisions to it. The new site is an entirely new entity with its own database, so I will not be migrating anything from the currently live site to it.

The new site has the same domain name as the original, live site. When the new site is ready I will point the DNS on GoDaddy to the new host. This is the first time I've tried this, and I've run into a problem.

Which is, that I can't access or even log in to the staged site because the DNS still points to GoDaddy. I thought that installing a staged version of the new site in a subdomain on the new host server, and then using a temp URL to access it, would work, but sadly I've have found out it will not.

Tech support at the new webhost were stumped on how I could achieve this, but finally came up with the idea of creating a subdomain on the GoDaddy server and then pointing the subdomain DNS to the new webhost. I don't like this idea, as I don't want to take the slightest chance of interrupting or damaging the current live site.

I came up with what I hope is an elegant, simple solution, but I want to get opinions from people who may have tried it already and discovered if it works, or if it's a totally stupid idea that is bound to fail.

I have added two lines to the wp-config file, for *define( 'WP_HOME'* and *define( 'WP_SITEURL'* and used the temp URL and directory location info of the new staging site. It seems to work just fine. Down the line, when the new site on the new host is ready to go live, I will point the DNS to the new host and delete the two lines in the wp-config file.

SO FINALLY to my question: Is this indeed a brilliant solution, or is there a real possibility it will it cause me major problems like broken links and database corruption in the future?

Comment: this sounds complicated, have you considered adding an entry in your computers hosts file instead so that your browser goes to the new host? I'm also unsure what would be an accepted answer, can you clearly state your question? This isn't a discussion forum, you need to ask a clear question that can be answered factually and fully for all people with that question, not a discussion or varied opinions/advice

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I don't know how to do what you suggest with a hosts file. And that wouldn't be a good solution for my client if don't know how to explain it to him so he could also access the site that way.

I'm sorry if  I wasn't clear, I tried to be. It seems a simple yes or no question. Is temporarily editing the wp-config file a way to accomplish what I need, or is it going to lead to problems.

Comment: then migrate to a new URL, eitherway there is no right or wrong answer here, and you need a question that has a right, correct answer, that you can mark as accepted. _Despite what you think there is no simple yes or no here_, there are lots of ways to solve your problem, and no canonical official correct way, and the answer is _it depends_ and _sometimes_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SO FINALLY to my question: Is this indeed a brilliant solution, or is there a real possibility it will it cause me major problems like broken links and database corruption in the future?

You will find that new content created refers to the new URL, even after you remove the config statements, and old content may still refer to the original URL.

So yes, it will cause problems. You can't change a sites URL by adding defines to the config file, the database needs migrating too with an appropriate search replace tool. ( an SQL query is not that tool ).

There are many ways to achieve your goal, this is not it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, a simple yes or no answer to whether my idea would work or not. I suspected it would be NO. Sorry for wording the question so confusingly, Tom. I realize now that the title in particular is misleading and implies I'm asking "how do I stage..."